# Lightning:input required always true

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

I have a lightning component like the below,

```
<aura:component description="GDPR_Settings_Configuration" implements="force:appHostable">
<aura:attribute name="gdprSetting" type="Object" description="The GDPR Configuration setting" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleInit}" />

<lightning:card title="GDPR Auto Processing Configuration">
        <br/>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-col_padded slds-m-horizontal--small">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">Condition</div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">Year value to build query to satisfy respected condition.</div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small"></div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">
                <lightning:input label="Contacts Agreement Condition" name="contactsAgreementCondition" type="checkbox" value="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c}" checked="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c}" />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">
                <lightning:input type="number" min="1" label="Contacts Agreement Year Value" name="contactsAgreementYearValue" value="{!v.gdprSetting.Agreements_Year_Value__c}" placeholder="Contacts Agreement Year Value" variant="label-hidden" disabled="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c == true ? false : true}" required="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c == true ? true : false}"/>
            </div>
         </div>
</lightning:card>
<div class="slds-text-align_right slds-m-horizontal_x-large">
        <lightning:button name="save" label="SAVE" onclick="{!c.updateGDPRDetails}" variant="brand" />
</div>
</aura:component>
```

In the above code, I have a front end validation as if the contactsAgreementCondition is true then the contactsAgreementYearValue value should be required.

But in the front end, the validation always takes as follows,

When I checked contactsAgreementCondition,

[image]

When I uncheck the contactsAgreementCondition value also show the same error in the front-end.

[image]

What I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with 2-way binding so you need to trigger the check on change of checkbox:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">
            <lightning:input label="Contacts Agreement Condition" 
                             onchange="{!c.checkIfRequired}" 
                             name="contactsAgreementCondition" 
                             type="checkbox" 
                             checked="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c}" />
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-bottom_small">
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactsAgreement" 
                             type="number" 
                             min="1" 
                             label="Contacts Agreement Year Value" 
                             name="contactsAgreementYearValue" 
                             placeholder="Contacts Agreement Year Value" 
                             variant="label-hidden" 
                             disabled="{!!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c}" 
                             required="{!v.gdprSetting.Contacts_Agreements_Condition__c}"/>
        </div>
```

In JS:

```
checkIfRequired : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("contactsAgreement").reportValidity();
}
```

**Note:** 2-way binding does not work properly and so we have many fixes in AURA framework. After a while, LWC came up which is one way binding for this reason.